Microsoft graph subscription list - How to send the updated item to a subscription
I have a durable azure function that should be called when an item sharepoint list is updated. I've added a subscription
{
    ChangeType = "updated",
    NotificationUrl = $"https://XXXXxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/startapproval",
    Resource = "sites/" + site.Id + "/lists/" + list.Id + "/",
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
    ClientState = "ApprovalProcess",
    LatestSupportedTlsVersion = "v1_2"
}

When I update on item, the azure function is called but I don't have the updated item information.
How do I know which item has been updated?
In the previous version of the durable azure function, an xml was obtained with the updated item data. Now I don't see the option even in the documentary.

If you want to target a specific item from the list, modify your subscription to target the specific list item.
"Resource": "sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}"

If your updated target is any item from the list, keep your original subscription and get the updated item Id as follows:
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var graphApiUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge {DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")}";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(graphApiUrl);

string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

foreach (var item in items.value)
{
    // Extract item ID and perform desired actions
    string itemId = item.id;
}


Quite nice idea, but just a rough sketch, cause the graph call will never succeed, due to the missing authentication. Also probably consider using the Graph SDK to avoid deserialization on your own. Last but not least, a subscription hook can according to the documentation take up to five minutes. So the filter should use that time window and handle multiple retrievements.

I agree. Using the graph SDK is a better approach. Furthermore, utilizing incremental retrievements could help handle potential delays in subscription hook notifications, ensuring that all modified items within the specified time window are retrieved.

Would you tell me whether your issue has been resolved or have any update? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.
